# overlay class_loader, cannot catkin_make

Tags: ros, compilation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to overlay http://wiki.ros.org/class_loader in my environment. As far as I can tell, it's a catkin package, so I've cloned the git repo into the src directory of my catkin workspace.

First it was complaining about the cmake_modules package. It didn't look like I had that ros package, so I just checked out its source too. Now it's not complaining about that anymore.

I am on Groovy and Ubuntu 12.04. I have the ubuntu package libpoco-dev already  installed.

Here are the current complaints:

```
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'cmake_modules'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(cmake_modules)
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'class_loader'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(class_loader)
CMake Error at class_loader/CMakeLists.txt:10 (find_package):
  Could not find module FindPoco.cmake or a configuration file for package
  Poco.

  Adjust CMAKE_MODULE_PATH to find FindPoco.cmake or set Poco_DIR to the
  directory containing a CMake configuration file for Poco.  The file will
  have one of the following names:

    PocoConfig.cmake
    poco-config.cmake



CMake Error at /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:159 (message):
  catkin_package() DEPENDS on 'Poco' which must be find_package()-ed before.
  If it is a catkin package it can be declared as CATKIN_DEPENDS instead
  without find_package()-ing it.
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  /opt/ros/groovy/share/catkin/cmake/catkin_package.cmake:98 (_catkin_package)
  class_loader/CMakeLists.txt:11 (catkin_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
```

EDIT:

I hadn't checked out the `groovy-devel` branch. Now when try to build, it gets further and eventually produces the following errors:

```
In file included from /home/goretkin/code/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib/include/pluginlib/class_loader.h:301:0,
                 from /home/goretkin/code/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib/src/plugin_tool.cpp:30:
/home/goretkin/code/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib/include/pluginlib/class_loader_imp.h: In member function ‘std::vector > pluginlib::ClassLoader::getPluginXmlPaths(const string&, const string&, bool)’:
/home/goretkin/code/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib/include/pluginlib/class_loader_imp.h:182:72: error: no matching function for call to ‘getPlugins(const string&, const string&, std::vector >&, bool&)’
/home/goretkin/code/catkin_ws/src/pluginlib/include/pluginlib/class_loader_imp.h:182:72: note: candidates are:
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/package.h:108:18: note: void ros::package::getPlugins(const string&, const string&, ros::package::V_string&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/package.h:108:18: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 4 provided
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/package.h:114:18: note: void ros::package::getPlugins(const string&, const string&, ros::package::M_string&)
/opt/ros/groovy/include/ros/package.h:114:18: note:   candidate expects 3 arguments, 4 provided
make[2]: *** [pluginlib/CMakeFiles/plugin_tool.dir/src/plugin_tool.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [pluginlib/CMakeFiles/plugin_tool.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

Presumably I have to also pull the latest `ros/package.h`?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/206276/overlay-class_loader,-cannot-catkin_make/) by [gustavogoretkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/11151/gustavogoretkin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2015-03-30

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [2ROS0](https://answers.ros.org/users/18936/2ros0/) on 2015-03-30**:
Can we see your CMakeLists.txt?

**Comment by [gustavogoretkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/11151/gustavogoretkin/) on 2015-05-01**:
@2ROS0, sorry about the delay. given the new edits, should I still post the `CMakeLists.txt`? I am guessing you mean the class_loader one, not the top-level workspace one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> I am on Groovy and Ubuntu 12.04

and

> First it was complaining about the cmake_modules package. It didn't look like I had that ros package, so I just checked out its source too. Now it's not complaining about that anymore.

While `cmake_modules` has been released into Groovy (as `ros-groovy-cmake-modules`), the `groovy-devel` version of `class_loader` doesn't seem to use it (`CMakeLists.txt` [here](https://github.com/ros/class_loader/blob/ed7a66256abee2bd5a5bfcca276a545c1f18ec29/CMakeLists.txt)).

Are you trying to build the `indigo-devel` branch on Groovy, or do you want to use the `groovy-devel` version?

---

Edit: just tested this on a clean Groovy workspace (with the `groovy-devel` branch of `class_loader`) and it builds without error.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gustavogoretkin](https://answers.ros.org/users/11151/gustavogoretkin/) on 2015-05-01**:
Sorry about the delay. I think I suspected that I was running into a bug in the release of `class_loader` on my system, so I probably wanted to try building the groovy-devel version, but I mistakenly(probably) buidling from the indigo release. I've updated my question.